# Ruby on Rails - Count Entries on Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, scaffold

In a simple Ruby on Rails applicaiton, I have a Scaffold called "Proposals" on which one of its columns is a string called "creationyear". I'm trying to count how many proposals have been created each year when the index page is loaded doing the following (in "proposals_controller.rb" file):

```
def index
  @proposals = Proposal.all
  @count2015 = Proposal.count(:all, :conditions => "creationyear = 2015")
  @count2016 = Proposal.count(:all, :conditions => "creationyear = 2016")
end
```

Somehow it is not working, since it gives me back on both variables the total number of entries on the scaffold.

Does anyone knows how to solve this one? I'm using Rails v4.2.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@count2015 = Proposal.where(creationyear: '2015').count
```

If `creationyear` is a string, otherwise without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are fine, but it's worth providing a bit of background.

The way that `count` is used in Active Record has changed since earlier versions of Rails. It's possible you found an example from Rails 3 or earlier where conditions could be specified in the way you tried.

In more recent versions of Rails, `count` can be called with a column name e.g.

```
Person.count(:email) # number of person records that have an email address
```

but is used in other cases by creating the scope first, for instance by using `where`, and then calling `count` on that:

```
Proposal.where(creationyear: '2015').count
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not you group the proposals by year?

```
@proposals = Proposal.group(:creationyear).count
```

or

```
@proposals = Proposal.group('creationyear').select('*, COUNT(*) as quantity')
```

This will reduce the queries happening for every year to one single query.